# Problem with setting cookie in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cookies

I am having a problem setting a cookie through PHP on IE. It works for any other browser but for IE. I have noticed that if i make the call for setting a cookie on IE and then making a request for it (same or next page) it doesn't work but if i land on the page and then refresh it, the cookie is set.

The way i am doing it is:

```
setcookie('ckone', $ck_one,$session_expiration_time,'/');
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had an IE issue (concerning iFrame) a while ago and was able to get rid of it with the following line of code:

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```